# What is the correct usage of ceph-objectsore-tool?

Tags: ceph

I am trying to export data for pg, but am getting errors from ceph-objectstore-tool.  I see some examples online of usage which seem to match this, and reading through the usage statement that the tool generates does not at all clarify what is wrong with this call.  It seems I am missing a command, but surely that is the purpose of `--op export`.  How can I fix this call?

```
$ ceph-objectstore-tool --op export -c $conf \
        --pgid 0.2180  --data-path ${ceph_data}/0.2180_head \
        --journal-path $j --file ${data_path}/0.2180.export  2>&1 | sed 1q
Invalid syntax, missing command

$ ceph -v
ceph version 0.80.11 (8424145d49264624a3b0a204aedb127835161070)
```

Since ceph is pretty old, perhaps an upgrade is in order.  Is an upgrade safe with incomplete placement groups? Can I use a more recent ceph-objectstore-tool on the data files used by the older ceph?